# Greenplum date/time field out of range: "10/10/2020"

Tags: insert, date, jdbc, greenplum

I'm testing Greenplum (which is based of Postegres) with a table of this form:

```
CREATE TABLE whiteglove (bigint BIGINT,varbinary bytea,boolean BOOLEAN,date DATE,decimal DECIMAL,double float,real REAL,integer INTEGER,smallint SMALLINT,timestamp TIMESTAMP,tinyint smallint,varchar VARCHAR)
```

Then I trying to insert this row using Postegres JDBC driver

```
INSERT INTO whiteglove VALUES (100000,'68656c6c6f',TRUE,'10/10/2020',0.5,1.234567,1.234,10,2,'4/14/2015 7:32:33PM',2,'hello')
```

which fails with the following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "10/10/2020"
  Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
  Position: 57
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:310)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:296)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:273)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:268)
```

If I take that same query and execute it from terminal using psql it passes without problems

```
dev=# select * from whiteglove ;
 bigint | varbinary | boolean | date | decimal | double | real | integer | smallint | timestamp | tinyint | varchar 
--------+-----------+---------+------+---------+--------+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+---------
(0 rows)

dev=# INSERT INTO whiteglove VALUES (100000,'68656c6c6f',TRUE,'10/10/2020',0.5,1.234567,1.234,10,2,'4/14/2015 7:32:33PM',2,'hello');
INSERT 0 1
dev=# select * from whiteglove ;
 bigint | varbinary  | boolean |    date    | decimal |  double  | real  | integer | smallint |      timestamp      | tinyint | varchar 
--------+------------+---------+------------+---------+----------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------+---------+---------
 100000 | 68656c6c6f | t       | 2020-10-10 |     0.5 | 1.234567 | 1.234 |      10 |        2 | 2015-04-14 19:32:33 |       2 | hello
(1 row)
```

Any pointers on why I'm getting this out of range error??

Comment: thanks for sharing so it maybe it is related to the date support in the JDBC!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the Java code you are using. Looks like you are passing dates as Strings rather then proper `java.time.LocalDate` or at least `java.sql.Date` instances. If you use constant values (rather than a `PreparedStatement`), always provide date values in an unambiguous format, e.g. `date '2020-07-22'`

Comment: yeah that's a true I'm passing a string date and use `stmt.execute(queryString)` with the query above